# Removing duplicate XML markup with awk

Tags: awk, sed

Looking to replace duplicate instances over two lines such as:

```
<\section>
     <\section>
```

with a single `</section>` entry.

Amount of white space in input file may vary.

If this can be done with sed, all the better. But maybe I need to use awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ez 's:(<\\section>)[[:space:]]+\1:</section>:'
```

Comment: 1) `\n` is already included in `[:space:]` so `[[:space:]\n]` = `[[:space:]]`, 2) that regexp would match multiple `<\section>`s on a single line or with many lines of spaces between them which may not be desirable, 3) the OP wants to output `</section>`, not `<\section>`, so you can't us `\1` in the replacement, 4) you have `:`s in the character class so also using `:`s as the delimiter obfuscates the code at best (I'd actually have expected it to break but I haven't tested it).

Comment: Works with a simple test  document, after changing \section to the required /section match

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed for `-E`, `-z` and `\s`:

```
$ sed -Ez 's:(<\\section>)\s*\n\s*\1:</section>:g' file
</section>
```

That would allow multiple empty lines or lines of blanks between 2 occurrences of `<\section>`, if that's undesirable then replace each `\s` with `[[:blank:]]`. It will also read the whole of the input into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;s/(<\\section>)\s*\n\s*\1/<\/section>/;P;D' file
```

Open a two line window and using pattern matching substitute the required string.

Comment: This seems to work OK, after changing the \\section match to \/section